# Realm ORM: how to deal with Maps?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am creating an Android app and I need to persist a `Map<String,MyClass>`.
I've just started to use [Realm ORM](https://realm.io), as it supports one-to-one and one-to-many, enumerations and lists. I also found a workaround for lists of strings (i.e. I have to create a StringWrapper class encapsulating a string.
However, from the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) I understand there is no easy way like `RealmMap`, as it happens for lists.
So, I'm looking for the best way to persist a map.
My current idea is to replace my map with a list of objects `KeyValueObject` encapsulating a `String` (the former map key) and a `MyClass`. Similarly to [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).
Is there any other solution that does not need me to rework the domain model for technology reasons?

Comment: Are you open to considering another product for persistence? Assuming that the Map object is an attribute of a containing model class, will storing the Map object in a blob column in the database meet your application needs?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: Please check out JDXA ORM (http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html). JDXA supports one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many relationships. JDXA also supports a notion of storing embedded objects (e.g., a HashMap) in a BLOB column. Although you can not do any query based on the HashMap values but JDXA will reconstruct the embedded HashMap object for you during a query.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you notice, Realm doesn't yet support maps: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/759

You could use the model classes:

```
class MyData extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<MyMapEntry> myMap;
}

class MyMapEntry extends RealmObject {
    private String key;
    private MyClass value;
}
```

Say you have a `MyData` object called `myData` and you wish to fetch the value associated with `myKey`, the query `MyClass myClass = myData.getMyMap().where().equalTo("key", myKey).firstFirst()` might be useful.

Comment: Notice that this might cause some limitations as shown in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061496/realm-serializing-data-from-map)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do have the luxury of reworking the persistence layer a bit, then the simplest solution is to not use a `Map<String` at all.

A `Map<String` literally means that a particular String is associated with one object. You can do the same thing just by having that String be part of your RealmObject. Then you can query based on that.

So any RealmResults` with a query for the string will contain one element, and that element will be the value of said map.