# Realm Java: Support for HashMap and LatLng

Tags: java, android, realm

In my android app, I am trying to store my data using Realm and my data structure looks like this.
It's a list of `CrimeDatabase` objects. `CrimeDatabase` has two attributes: `Date` and `HashMap<LatLng, CrimeIncident>`. The `HashMap`'s key is `LatLng` which stores the coordinates of crimes and `CrimeIncident` is my custom class object which stores other information. So in short, the my data-structure **visually** looks like this:

```
DATE 08/01/2017
   - HashMap<LatLng, CrimeIncident>
      - LatLng: 39.9526° N, 75.1652° W
      - CrimeIncident: Address, Time, CrimeType
   - HashMap<LatLng, CrimeIncident>
      - LatLng: 39.9530° N, 75.1648° W
      - CrimeIncident: Address, Time, CrimeType
DATE 08/02/2017
   - HashMap<LatLng, CrimeIncident>
      - LatLng: 39.9533° N, 75.1659° W
      - CrimeIncident: Address, Time, CrimeType
   - HashMap<LatLng, CrimeIncident>
      - LatLng: 39.9524° N, 75.1630° W
      - CrimeIncident: Address, Time, CrimeType
```

Below is my code. I followed the approach of wrapping the CrimeDatabase Object inside RealmList from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317595/6267116)

```
public class CrimeRealmObject extends RealmObject {
    public RealmList<CrimeDatabase> crimeMap;
}

public class CrimeDatabase extends RealmObject {
    private Date date;
    private HashMap<LatLng, CrimeIncident> myHashMap;
}
```

Realm is not even allowing me to put `HashMap` inside `CrimeDatabase` object. I even tried creating a `RealmHashMap` class with key/value attributes but it threw an error saying `LatLng` was not supported.

Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: `Map` is not supported by Realm. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311755/realm-orm-how-to-deal-with-maps for workaround.

Comment: I know about that and I have tried that answer. Please read the bottom half of my question.

Comment: If LatLng is not supported, how about creating an object with double attribute (for both latitude and longitude instead)? you can create a method later to create a LatLng objects from the double attributes later.

Comment: @ParthBhoiwala put `@Ignore` on your `myHashMap` to let realm ignore it. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#ignoring-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily map that structure into a single RealmObject each, save them into the Realm,  and make your life much easier.

```
CrimeIncident extends RealmObject  {
     Date date;
     double lat;
     double lng;
     String address;
     Date time;
     String crimeType;
```

Then if you need the objects for a given date, just do a RealmQuery with that given date as a condition

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So do I have to put all `CrimeIncident` objects in a big `RealmList` and query the entire database to fetch crime incidents for a certain date? Or can I put them in some sort of HashMap in Realm for faster access to the data?

Comment: What? No RealmList involved, only this object. Theb you get them as RealmResults when you query them